# How to detect third party login is 2fa enabled

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4, two-factor-authentication

I have an Identity server 4 application.  Which allows our customers to login with our login and with Google and Facebook third party logins (facebook and google).   We also have 2fa (Two factor) login ablity.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        }).AddGoogle("Google", options =>
            {
                options.AccessType = "offline";
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
                options.ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("Settings:GoogleClientId").Value;
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetSection("Settings:GoogleClientSecret").Value;
            })
            .AddFacebook("Facebook", facebookOptions =>
            {
                facebookOptions.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
                facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration.GetSection("Settings:FacebookAppId").Value;
                facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration.GetSection("Settings:FacebookAppSecret").Value;
            });
```

All of this works.   However I have a requirement from upper management.

Users who are supporters (there is a flag in the system for this) must have two factor enabled.   That was quite simple I just made this a requirement that they couldn't disable the two factor within our system.

However we soon discovered an issue with this.  If a user has two factor enabled on their google account. They then login in with google have to supply the two factor code and then they come back to our system where they again have to supply the two factor code for our system.

Is there a way to detect that the user had two factor enabled on their google account?  Once I know it was enabled there them i can stop ask them for the two factor code on our system.  I have looked everywhere and this information does not appear to be returned to me.  Nor does there appear to be any google api that would let me know if it was enabled on their account.

Comment: Thats the exact answer i was looking for.   Now i can take that to management.  Now should i delete this or leave it as its probably wondered a bit better than the original question.

Comment: Leaving it up is a good idea since people might find this one via google instead of the other one and now they have a link to follow to get the answer. Closed duplicates are good signposts.

Comment: I have sent an email to the author of the other answer I happen to know him.  with my use case I will update if I hear anything interesting back from Google